# Listing Usernames with five different values (based on $_GET) in another column

Tags: sql

I have a project where the goal for Usernames is to visit all 5 locations in a City. There are multiple cities. They can also visit one location in a city multiple times (hence the identical rows).

I have a table where in one column there is a Username and in another column the location they have visited:

| Username | City |
| --- | --- |
| Esiul | Chicago 1 |
| Esiul | Chicago 2 |
| Esiul | Chicago 1 |
| Esiul | Chicago 3 |
| Esiul | Chicago 5 |
| Another | Chicago 5 |
| Esiul | Chicago 4 |
| Esiul | Chicago 1 |
| Esiul | Atlanta 1 |
| Esiul | Atlanta 3 |
| Esiul | Atlanta 2 |
| Another | Atlanta 2 |
| Another | Atlanta 1 |
| Another | Atlanta 1 |
| Another | Atlanta 3 |
| Another | Atlanta 5 |
| Another | Atlanta 4 |

I would like to output the list of Usernames who have visited all five different points in a certain City (I get the City from $_GET["city"]).

I am studying SQL, struggling with this query and would be so very much grateful if anyone could lead me to the right direction.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `WHERE` to filter for the city you want.  Then you use aggregation and filter using `count(distinct)`.  Given the data you have shown:

```
select username
from t
where city like 'Chicago %'
group by username
having count(distinct city) = 5;
```

I would caution that the `city` column is not really a "city"; it is a "location".  Based on the question, I would expect the table to have at least three columns:

- User id of some sort
- City (such as `'Chicago'` and `'Atlanta'`)
- Location

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Oh, and there are two columns. One has Locations (City + number) and the other one is for Usernames.

Thanks again!